# Google Charts API: Always show the Data Point Values in Graph

Tags: google-visualization

Is it possible to always show the data point values in Line/Bar charts? by default values values are shown only when hovering on the data points as tooltip.

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can use this:

```
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
```

Comment: perfect! This seems to work for Line Charts. Not able to get this working on Bar Charts: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart (Any help greatly appreciated). Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this one then: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#image_bar_chart

Answer (score 10):

You can simply use **pointSize** option which is set to 0 by default.

> pointSize: Diameter of displayed points in pixels. Use zero to hide all points. You can override values for individual series using the series property.