# Google Charts API : Display Data Points (PHP + MySQL)

Tags: php, javascript

I came across this thread which is exactly what I want [Google Charts API: Always show the Data Point Values in Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449467/google-charts-api-always-show-the-data-point-values-in-graph) but the answer given there applies when using hard coded values.

In my case, I use MySQL data to populate the chart and hence can't figure out where and how exactly to use the `role:annonation` attribute. I'm using the following code to draw the chart.

#### PHP

```
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Month', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Benchmark', 'type' => 'number')
    );  


$rows = array();

foreach($someArray as $mnth=>$array)
{
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $mnth);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $benchMark);
    foreach($array as $pt)
    {       
        $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $pt);
    }
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}
$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

#### Javascript

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);
      var options = {
          title: 'TNS',titleTextStyle: {color: "green"}, hAxis: {title: "MONTH", titleTextStyle: {color: "green"}}, vAxis: {title: "Percentage", titleTextStyle: {color: "green"},viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
        viewWindow: {
          max: 110,
          min: 0
        }},
          is3D: 'true',
          height:600,
          colors: ['black', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']         
           };


        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('tns1'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

    }
```

Comment: This should be tagged 'Javascript' and Google Graph Api' instead of PHP or are you having trouble populating the table with data, as well?

Comment: No. Populating table with data is not a problem. I tagged it PHP as I thought the code might be applied to any PHP code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. All I had to do was add this to the options:

```
pointSize: 10
```

so that my configuration options becomes

```
var options = {
          title: 'TNS',titleTextStyle: {color: "green"}, hAxis: {title: "MONTH", titleTextStyle: {color: "green"}}, vAxis: {title: "Percentage", titleTextStyle: {color: "green"},viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
          viewWindow: {
             max: 110,
             min: 0
          }},
          pointSize: 10, // <----- this is what did the trick
          is3D: 'true',
          height:600,
          colors: ['black', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']         
};
```

SOURCE : [Google Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#Discrete_vs_Continuous)