# Google Charts API: Show Data Point Values in Line Chart

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

I'm pretty new to PHP and was given a project that uses Google Visualization.
In the code below, how do I permanently display the data values and data points on the line chart?

Things I've tried:
1. Setting `pointSize` to some value
2. Setting `dataOpacity` to 1
3. Adding this annotation column `<? php echo {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'} ?>,` as suggested here: [Google Charts API: Always show the Data Point Values using arrayToDataTable. How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771630/google-charts-api-always-show-the-data-point-values-using-arraytodatatable-how)
but gota server error instead. I'm probably doing this wrong.

Appreciate your help. Thanks!

```
function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Payout Ratio'],
        [<?php echo json_encode(date('Y', strtotime('-1 year'))); ?>,  <?php echo json_encode($oneYearAgoPayoutRatio); ?>],
        [<?php echo json_encode(date('Y', strtotime('-2 year'))); ?>,  <?php echo json_encode($twoYearsAgoPayoutRatio); ?>],
        [<?php echo json_encode(date('Y', strtotime('-3 year'))); ?>,  <?php echo json_encode($threeYearsAgoPayoutRatio); ?>],
        [<?php echo json_encode(date('Y', strtotime('-4 year'))); ?>,  <?php echo json_encode($fourYearsAgoPayoutRatio); ?>],
        [<?php echo json_encode(date('Y', strtotime('-5 year'))); ?>,  <?php echo json_encode($fiveYearsAgoPayoutRatio); ?>]
    ]);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Payout Ratio',
    },
    backgroundColor: '#fafbfc',
    colors: ['#3073b5'],
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('payout_ratio'));

  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you struggle to get the proper data aggregated or get the proper data visualized properly?

Comment: A good way to debug an error is to analyze the error message. Could you tell us which error you get?

Comment: you're using a _Material_ line chart (`google.charts.Line`) vs. a _Classic_ (`google.visualization.LineChart`) -- there are a number of options that are not supported by _Material_, including `pointSize` & `dataOpacity`, as well as column roles (annotations),  see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some experimentation, it seems that Material Line Chart does not support annotations at the moment. Have updated my code to use the Classic Line Chart instead and followed @asgallant suggestion in [Google Charts API: Always show the Data Point Values using arrayToDataTable. How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771630/google-charts-api-always-show-the-data-point-values-using-arraytodatatable-how)  to use a DataView.

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Payout Ratio'],
          ['2004',  1.2],
          ['2005',  -0.25],
          ['2006',  2.5],
          ['2007',  5.8]
        ]);
        
        // Use view to show annotation
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0, 1, {
            calc: "stringify",
            sourceColumn: 1,
            type: "string",
            role: "annotation"
        },]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Payout Ratio',
        backgroundColor: '#fafbfc',
        colors: ['#3073b5'],
        // Display data point
        pointSize: 5,
      };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("payout_ratio"));
        chart.draw(view, options);
    }
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="payout_ratio" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your annotation column should look like this according to the source you posted.

You posted:

```
<? php echo {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'} ?>
```

Example was:

```
[/* column headers */, {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}, /* column headers */]
```

Also that is js so you don't need to echo it out in the php.

So that section of your code block would look like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [/* column headers */, {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}, /* column headers */],        
    ['Year', 'Payout Ratio'],
    [<?php echo json_encode(date('Y', strtotime('-1 year'))); ?>,  <?php echo json_encode($oneYearAgoPayoutRatio); ?>],
    [<?php echo json_encode(date('Y', strtotime('-2 year'))); ?>,  <?php echo json_encode($twoYearsAgoPayoutRatio); ?>],
    [<?php echo json_encode(date('Y', strtotime('-3 year'))); ?>,  <?php echo json_encode($threeYearsAgoPayoutRatio); ?>],
    [<?php echo json_encode(date('Y', strtotime('-4 year'))); ?>,  <?php echo json_encode($fourYearsAgoPayoutRatio); ?>],
    [<?php echo json_encode(date('Y', strtotime('-5 year'))); ?>,  <?php echo json_encode($fiveYearsAgoPayoutRatio); ?>]
]);
```

Comment: Although I didn't go this route, the proper way to use this is
   ```...```
   ```['Year', {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}, 'Payout Ratio'],
       [<?php echo json_encode(date('Y', strtotime('-1 year'))); ?>, 
     <?php echo json_encode($oneYearAgoPayoutRatio); ?>, 
     <?php echo json_encode($oneYearAgoPayoutRatio); ?>],```
   ```...```
  
I wanted to show the Payout Ratio as the annotation, thus I echoed it under the annotation column.

Comment: @fab Im glad you figured it out.