# Google Line Chart - Show Data Values on Points by default

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I want to show data values on the line chart, i.e. which appear on mouse over, i need them all displayed by default. I tried the solution here [Google Charts API: Always show the Data Point Values in Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449467/google-charts-api-always-show-the-data-point-values-in-graph)

```
data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'annotation'});
```

I added this to my code (I'm not sure where to put it exactly) but It didn't make any change.

Here is part of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Week/Orders</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart(){

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

                ['Week','Orders'],
                <?php
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aresult)){
                        echo "['".$row["Week"]."', ".$row["Orders"]."],";
                    }
                ?>

               ]);


            var options = {
                title: 'Week Vs Orders',
                'width':1700,
                'height':600,

                legend: { position: 'bottom' }
                     };

               var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curvechart')); 
               chart.draw(data, options);  

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="curvechart" style="width: 900px; height: 400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have two values; Week and Orders. I need only the "Order" value displayed on the graph by default. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use a `DataView` to add annotations to the chart

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
}]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart(){
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Week','Orders'],
        ['1', 5],
        ['2', 6],
        ['3', 4]
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1, {
        calc: 'stringify',
        sourceColumn: 1,
        type: 'string',
        role: 'annotation'
    }]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Week Vs Orders',
        width: 1700,
        height: 600,
        legend: {position: 'bottom'}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curvechart'));

    chart.draw(view, options);  // <-- use data view
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="curvechart"></div>
```

Comment: how to deal if my chart has 2 verticals e.g Followers vs Following ?

Comment: not sure I follow your question, two lines on the chart? you can add an annotation column after each series column...

Comment: I made it work with this

  view.setColumns(
          [0, 1, {
          calc: 'stringify',
          sourceColumn: 1,
          type: 'string',
          role: 'annotation'
          }, 2 , {
          calc: 'stringify',
          sourceColumn: 2,
          type: 'string',
          role: 'annotation'
          }] 
      );